# Better way for multi OR work with AND in TypeORM?

Tags: sql, orm, typeorm

As I know in TypeOrm, `OR` operator will be an `Array` with cases.

```
{
  where: [...]
}
```

That ok if `OR` on 1 field. but if I have a query like: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (age = 20 OR age = 22 OR age = 23) AND (name LIKE '%kan%' OR username LIKE '%kan%')`

That mean I must pass an Array with 6 (*3 age* * *2 name/username*) object match all cases I want

```
{
  where: [
    {
      age: 20,
      name: Like('%kan%')
    },
    {
      age: 20,
      username: Like('%kan%')
    },
    {
      age: 22,
      name: Like('%kan%')
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

It seem not really good. Can I do that with other better way?

Comment: Never store age. People become older every year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date of birth instead.

Comment: @jarlh it is an example

Answer (score 0):

Other way.

```
AsIs:
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (age = 20 OR age = 22 OR age = 23) AND (name LIKE '%kan%' OR username LIKE '%kan%')
```

```
ToBe(ORACLE):
SELECT *
FROM users a 
WHERE 1=1
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 'x' FROM DUAL WHERE a.age = 20
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x' FROM DUAL WHERE a.age = 22
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x' FROM DUAL WHERE a.age = 23
)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 'x' FROM DUAL WHERE a.name LIKE '%kan%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x' FROM DUAL WHERE a.username LIKE '%kan%'
)
```

Comment: thank for your ans. But I mean other way with TypeOrm, not raw query